# For loop Syntax in C strange form

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm analyzing a C program and i find this loop that i can't understand. There is no counter or limit or variable.

```
/* ioloop */
  for (;;)
  {
// statements

  }
```

is this an infinite loop ?

Comment: Yes it is infinite loop.. Please always Google first before asking.

Comment: Yes, it is (unless there is a `break` statement somewhere inside the loop).

Comment: @rici: Or a `return`.

Comment: @minigeek what's wrong with using stackoverflow not google ? it gives me always better and specific answers, can you explain me the issue of asking here ?

Comment: @stojo304 if you post low quality questions then your Account with IP gets banned... Like me :( hope you understand why this community is so strong. It keeps a valuable and non-redundant data so as to keep valuable info for future visitor.like you searched for this question...but already ans to this question existed..only thing i want to say is stackoverflow has an automatic algorithm of banning account and IP once your account gets low votes.or duplication.if you delete question thats even worst...i m suffering from it now..can answer only :/ gud luck... http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997

Comment: But you didn't use SO instead of google - asking a question that has been answered innumerable times is not the same as searching for that information, thereby cluttering SO with something that is fantastically easy to find.

Comment: @minigeek oh thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an idiomatic way of writing a potentially infinite loop in C.

Alternatives such as `while(1)` often issued a compiler warning.

Answer (score 1):

It is an infinite loop. Hopefully, there is a `break` statement in the loop somewhere. A `break` statement will cause the loop to exit.